# How to deploy app on Google Compute engine similar to app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to deploy and app using compute engine as my company does not provide access to app engine yet. Is there a way to deploy the same app using compute engine rather than app engine on google cloud. I have searched multiple forum but unable to find relevant answers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your language? What's your framework?

Comment: Want to use python version 3 on Linux Compute engine...

Answer (score 1):

With python3, I recommend you to write a [Flask web application](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/). Your web application will be similar on App Engine and on your compute.

However, you have several things to perform at the infrastructure level. I recommend you to have a look to [managed Instances group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) with auto scaling and health check and [Global load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/).

*Note: Because, it's not serverless, you have to pay at least 1 instance even if there isn't traffic on your app*

Alternatively, you can have a look to [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) (easier VM management and scaling) and [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/).

Comment: Thanks...but how make the app communicate with external source using the instance...I am able to launch the flask app....how to get an https url for the external app....

Comment: You can take a look at the [Official-documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm) this procedure is well explained

Comment: If you have only one compute, you can use the solution of @Chris32. However, if you want to reproduce the elasticity of App Engine and you use an managed instances group, you have to use a global load balancer as described if my answer. If it's not clear for you, add more detail to your question for having more precise answer